# How to update datetime column from a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For testing purpose I want to alter a column in a row
where `SELECT * FROM CSEReduxResponses WHERE response_id=76`
The column I want to modify is `[approveddate] [datetime] NULL`,
Is there a way I can change the date? I will like to change it
to MARCH 2,2014. Right now is '2014-04-15 09:49:00.000'.

I have:

```
Microsoft sql server 2008
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.0.2531.0
```

Comment: Are you asking how to change the format or the actual date that is stored?

Comment: use the wrong words , should have put UPDATE , i have edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not getting what you want, but it sounds like you want a simple update query? If so, this should do it:

```
UPDATE CSEReduxResponses 
SET approveddate = '2014-03-02'
WHERE response_id = 76
```

How the date is displayed depends on your language settings, and can be altered when you issue your query, so if you want `March 03, 2014`instead of `2014-03-02`you can control it in the query.